# AWS Batch Job application not being able to send SNS notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, aws-batch

I have an AWS Batch Job which is a .NET CORE app running as a container which downloads from an SFTP server a CSV parses it and inserts data into AWS RDS.

When the CSV is corrupt the job is failing and is supposed to send a SNS notification, instead I see the following error in CloudWatch logs.

```
 "Message": "User: arn:aws:sts::654001826221:assumed-role/fileimportworker-batch/5f77c736e4e64c2d82df278800ec4f25 is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:accountIdHere:Test-SNS-Batch",
```

My IAM role attached to the batch Job role has SNS:Published allowed, S3 allowed, also provides read access to 2 secrets in Secret Manager. S3 and SecretManager access work, the task is able to download the file from SFTP and put it to S3 and also to read the RDS password from secret manager.

Comment: I have tried to create a simple Docker container with AWS CLI, I run it on my machine with `docker run --env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=id_here --env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_here --env REGION=eu-west-1 --env TOPIC_ARN=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:account_id_here:Test-SNS-Batch aws_cli ` I get the message id and the message is delivered to my inbox.

Comment: When I create a new batch job definition with needed environment variables and when I submit the job I get `An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the Publish operation: User: arn:aws:iam::account_id_here:user/docker_test is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:account_id_here:Test-SNS-Batch`.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch Job may use credentials from a container instead of your environment variables. You have to look at credential precedence.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence

> The AWS CLI uses credentials and configuration settings located in
> multiple places, such as the system or user environment variables,
> local AWS configuration files, or explicitly declared on the command
> line as a parameter. Certain locations take precedence over others.
> The AWS CLI credentials and configuration settings take precedence in
> the following order:
>
> 1. Command line options – Overrides settings in any other location. You
>    can specify --region, --output, and --profile as parameters on the
>    command line.
> 2. Environment variables – You can store values in your system's
>    environment variables.
> 3. CLI credentials file – The credentials and config file are updated
>    when you run the command aws configure. The credentials file is
>    located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux or macOS, or at
>    C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows. This file can contain
>    the credential details for the default profile and any named profiles.
> 4. CLI configuration file – The credentials and config file are updated
>    when you run the command aws configure. The config file is located at
>    ~/.aws/config on Linux or macOS, or at C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\config
>    on Windows. This file contains the configuration settings for the
>    default profile and any named profiles.
> 5. Container credentials – You can associate an IAM role with each of
>    your Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) task definitions.
>    Temporary credentials for that role are then available to that task's
>    containers. For more information, see IAM Roles for Tasks in the
>    Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide.
> 6. Instance profile credentials – You can associate an IAM role with each
>    of your Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances. Temporary
>    credentials for that role are then available to code running in the
>    instance. The credentials are delivered through the Amazon EC2
>    metadata service. For more information, see IAM Roles for Amazon EC2
>    in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances and Using Instance
>    Profiles in the IAM User Guide.

P.S. To intergate AWS Batch with SNS without coding, you can use the Eventbridge rule to listen to event patterns from AWS Batch. You just select the target of the rule to publish the message on the SNS topic you want.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_sns_tutorial.html